# Show that if A is a finite set of non empty sets, then A has a choice function.

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove that if A is a finite set of non empty sets, then A has a choice function.

My approach is to construct such function. Since it is a finite set we can say that $A=\left \{ B_1,B_2,...,B_n \right \}$, then by the axiom of choice we can say that since $B_i$ with $1\leq i \leq n$ is non empty then every $B_i$ has a choice function. And WLOG we say that each choice function (let's call it $f_{B_i}$ for every set $B_i$) does this $f_{B_i}(B_{i})=b_{i}$, which means that $b_i \epsilon B_i$.

Then we look at $\wp(A)- \left \{ \emptyset \right \} $. And we define the function $\varphi : \wp(A)- \left \{ \emptyset \right \} $  ->$ \left \{ 1,2,..,n \right \} $ such that if $x \epsilon \wp(A)- \left \{ \emptyset \right \} $ then  $\varphi(x)= b_{min\left \{ i| Bi \epsilon X \right \}} $.

I thought that maybe that could be the function, but it doesn't seem like it. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: I didn't read past 'axiom of choice' because the axiom of choice immediately implies something even stronger than this. Are you sure you're allowed to use the AC? What version of the AC are you using?

Comment: I'm using the versiong which states "Every non empty set has a choice function", but our teacher told us we weren't allowed to say such thing that A is not empty, then it has. I still don't get why.

Comment: I take it you mean "every non-empty set of non-empty sets has a choice function". I didn't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: What I am trying to prove it that "Every non empty set has a choice functions" implies "A finite set of non empty sets has a choice function". Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Not every non-empty set has a choice function. Consider $\{\varnothing\}$. There is no function $\epsilon$ such that $\varepsilon (\varnothing)\in \varnothing$.

Comment: This was asked before, several times. Have you looked at other threads?

Comment: Every finite collection of *nonempty* sets has choice function, and we can prove it without using axiom of choice. You can prove it by induction for the number of elements of finite collection.